# "battles royal" vs. "battle royals"

Tags: word-order, plural-forms, adjective-phrases

On Wikipedia it is said:

> Battle royal (**plural battles royal**) traditionally refers to a fight involving three or more combatants that is fought until only one fighter remains standing. In recent times the term has been used in a more general sense to refer to any fight involving large numbers of people that are not organized into factions.

(Emphasis mine)

Why is the plural "battles royal" rather than "battle royals"?

Comment: Carlo, did you spell that correctly? I have heard of *battle royale*, with a letter *e* on the end. It's a film. See http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0266308/

Comment: @Tristan The wiki article does indeed say "battle royal", though I agree it ought to be *royale*.

Comment: It seems both spellings are accepted. Again, it must be  French influence.

Comment: @Stephan, yes, as a matter of fact, French culture has always been held in special respect by the English and French expressions often seemed to have a *je ne sais quoi* which recommended them to the user.

Answer (score 6):

The term "battle royal" is an unusual construction because it uses the French custom of putting the adjective after the noun ([source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=Battle+royal)). As the word "battle" is the noun of the phrase, it takes the plural form. Adjectives do not have plural forms, so it does not make sense to say "battle royals".

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes English speakers use foreign constructions that sound "cool" and stylish.

"The Brothers Karamazov," "The Chicago Eight" (aka Conspiracy Eight/Conspiracy Seven), and other high profile trials where there are multiple defendants, etc. are other heightened and stylized examples.

Another example is the plural of Attorney General is Attorneys General.
https://abovethelaw.com/career-files/lawprose-lesson-116-whats-the-plural-form-of-attorney-general-and-what-is-the-plural-possessive/

Good Luck.